# Passing a Object with all information vs passing specific information

Tags: java, methods, parameters

We will be focusing on 5 important classes: Person, Car, House, Job, and ISP. Here is an example of the classes, so that we you can have a visual of what I am trying to say. The syntax will be a bit off.

```
public class Person() {
    private Car car;
    private House house;
    private Job job;
    private ISP isp;

    public Person(Car car, House house, Job job, ISP isp) {
    this.car = car;
    this.house = house;
    ...
    }

    public Car getCar() {
        ...
    }
}

public class Car() {
    private Make make;
    private Model model;
    private Color color;
    ...
}

public class House() {
    ...
}
```

I decide to create a static class; this class will contain only static methods that will take in parameters and perform some kind of action. Here are 3 examples and I was wondering which way would be the best way. I am pretty much trying to figure out when I should pass in the class that has all the required information vs. when I should just pass only the specifics, and find the pros and cons between them.

```
public static boolean hasStableLife(Person person) { //This is a made up method and the logic may not make sense at all
    Car car = person.getCar();
    House house = house.getHouse();
    Job job = job.getJob();
    if(car.getValue() > 40000 && (house.getValue() > 300000 && house.hasNoLoans()) && job.isFullTime()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean hasStableLife(Car car, House house, Job job) { //This is a made up method and the logic may not make sense at all
    if(car.getValue() > 40000 && (house.getValue() > 300000 && house.hasNoLoans()) && job.isFullTime()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean hasStableLife(long carValue, long houseValue, boolean hasNoLoans, boolean isFullTime) { //This is a made up method and the logic may not make sense at all
    if(carValue > 40000 && (houseValue > 300000 && hasNoLoans) && isFullTime) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the closest common ancestor in the relevant data hierarchy. In the case of `hasStableLife`, we're trying to label the *person*, so we should have access to all aspects of the person's life. If we wanted to know, say, `hasNiceCar`, then I would expect access to the full `Car` object. On the other hand, if we wanted to assess a particular property, then it would make sense to pass only the required data point, e.g., `isPastRetirement(int age)`.

Answer (score 0):

Three notes:

1- Always prefer less parameters (Zero parameters are even greater). This will help you maintain your code in the future.

2- Methods in java will send a copy of the primitives (e.g. int, long, char, .. etc), but in case of objects it will send a copy of the reference. Considering note 1 and 2, I believe that it is better to use the first approach.

3- You could of course reuse your code. For example, the first method could call the second by passing its own data as the following: 
p

```
public static boolean hasStableLife(Person person) {
    return this.hasStableLife(person.getCar(), person.getHouse(), person.getJob());
}
```

This could be very useful, but it depends on your requirements.

Comment: Does passing the Person object instead of the minimum requirements have any effect on the performance or anything else that I should be worried about?

Comment: No, there is no need to worry. Passing the object will only copy the reference and not the whole object. Therefore there would be no impact on memory nor performance. Also it will make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you will only ever call this method when you have a person object (who owns the car and the house) then you should use the first method, except you should make it a non-static method of the person class.

If you plan to use this without a person (which will not be possible with the first method) then I might change the name to something that describes what the method does more accurately, for example `isSufficientForStableLife(...)`.

Choosing between the second two is similar to the previous choice, do you want to be able to call the method without having car, house, and job objects?

Keep in mind you don't need to only have one of these methods, if you need the lowest level one which doesn't take objects occasionally but would also like to check if a person has a stable life you can implement both and call one from the other, for example :

```
public boolean hasStableLife() { 
   return isSufficientForStableLife(getCar(), getHouse(), getJob());
}

public static boolean isSufficientForStableLife(Car car, House house, Job job) {
    return isSufficientForStableLife(car.getValue(), house.getValue(), house.hasNoLoans(), job.isFullTime());
}
public static boolean isSufficientForStableLife(long carValue, long houseValue, boolean hasNoLoans, boolean isFullTime) { 
    return (carValue > 40000 && (houseValue > 300000 && hasNoLoans) && isFullTime);
}
```

Comment: This method was designed to be called only when you have a Person object, but I kept thinking to myself if it would be necessary to pass the entire object as opposed to just the required data.

Comment: I second Alex for making the methods non-static since these methods will only be called by the instantiated objects.